# How to make these password dots bigger in obscureText

Tags: dart, flutter

Check out this image below.

I want to make the password dots bigger.

[image]

[image]

I have tried TextStyle fontSize.

It did make these dots bigger.

But it will also make the password line higher.

That is not what I want.

Is there any solutions?

```
ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _usernameController,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              obscureText: true,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: could you add your code ?

Comment: so increasing the fontSize doesn't work for you , right ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use 'obscuringCharacter'

```
TextField(
  controller: _passwordController,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  obscureText: true,
  obscuringCharacter: '●',
),
```

and you can make it bigger using:

```
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
```

summary:

```
TextField(
  controller: _passwordController,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  obscureText: true,
  obscuringCharacter: '●',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
),
```

Answer (score 6):

Change to master channel (run `flutter channel master` and then `flutter upgrade`). After that, u can customize with the `obscuringCharacter` parameter inside `TextField`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `decoration` property of your `TextField` and set the `contentPadding` to zero.

```
     TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                obscureText: true,
                controller: _passwordController,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. These are password dots.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `TextFormField` https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html

It is also suggested in the Flutter docs. See https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField-class.html

> To integrate the TextField into a Form with other FormField widgets, consider using TextFormField.

Here you can set the `TextStyle` for whatever size you want.

Comment: OP mentioned he used `TextStyle`, not only it increased dots size but also `TextField/TextFormField` size.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad OP edited the question to address this issue.

Comment: OK that makes sense :) But did you try that on your own before writing it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can solve this. You can use `TextStyle`, bump up the `fontSize` and then adjust the `height` which adjusts line-height.

This isn't a great solution though because if a user wants to see the most recent character input like this `•••••ord` then your password font is gonna look different from the rest of the form.

Flutter, when obscuring just enters the • character as a mask. This character is different for each font and it is therefore probably better to just pick a different font.

That being said you could probably change that specific character's size but it would involve modifying the Flutter SDK at a deep level, which isn't something that's generally recommended.

Instead I think the best solution would be to modify the font itself so the `•` character displays in a fashion you like! Or just making your own obscuring widget!